# Searching for a specific number in a int variable

Tags: java, int

I'm currently "learning" JavaScript + Android Studio for school and I got a little problem for which I can't find the right answer on Google:

I want to know if an int variable has a specific number, for example, I'm looking for the number 7 now int numberOne = 25824 doesn't have a 7 inside, but int numberTwo = 12387 does have one. Is there a way to search for a specific number in int variables?

I tried converting the int into a new string variable, but somehow this doesn't work :(

Here's some code I'm working with:

```
public int round = 1;
public String nummerSieben = "" + round;

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    if (round % 7 == 0 || nummerSieben.contains("7")==true) {
      ....

    } else {

      ....
    }
  }
});
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you update `nummerSieben` whenever you update `round`?

Comment: That's Java, but you say you're working with JavaScript? What do you need the answer to be in?

Comment: "somehow this doesn't work" - how exactly doesn't that work?

Comment: Sorry, I'm always mixing those two languages, kind of new to those things :p Anyway I found a working solution with this right here: Integer.toString(round).contains("7")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int round = 1;
public String nummerSieben = "" + round; // nummerSieben is now "1"
```

You're hard-coding the value of nummberSieben.  You need presumably get some value from the view, and test that.  If you get it as in int, use

```
Integer.toString(i).contains("7") // i is whatever number you get from your view.
```

If you get it as a String, then half the work is already done, and you just need

```
i.contains("7")
```

As noted above, this has nothing to do with JavaScript - both your example and my answer are in Java.

Comment: This and Jordi Castillas answer solved my problem, I love you guys, thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

- Your comparison is not right, method `String:contains()` returns a boolean,
- Module `%` does not assert you the number will contain 7 or one of it's multiples.
- `Integer.toString(value)` converts easily your `int` to `String`.

Knowing this, you can do:

```
if (Integer.toString(round).contains("7")) {
     // IT CONTAINS THE NUMBER!
} else {
     // IT DOES NOT CONTAIN THE NUMBER
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm! What I've done now is this:  if (round % 7 == 0 || Integer.toString(round).contains("7")){

Comment: nice to hear that!!! just note that `number % 7 == 0` does not ensure there is a `7` in the number because `14 % 7 == 0` but there aren't any `7` in `14`....

Answer (score 0):

Here is perfect solution of your problem

```
public class Finder {
static int round = 123456789;
static String str = String.valueOf(round);

public static void main(String... args) {
    if (str.contains("7")) {
        System.out.println("Found");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Can't found...");
    }
  }
}
```

Just convert your integer to String and then try to found the specific value from that string.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I find this here to be an easier solution: Integer.toString(round).contains("7") - it's working perfect!

Comment: Yes @ChristianMögnumMöhrle but my example is also works perfectly. You can at-least up vote or accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert to string in order to search specific digit in integer.
You can use math for that purpose.
Here is the code:

```
private static boolean isFound(int round) {

    while (round > 0) {
        if (round % 10 == 7)
            return true;
        round /= 10;
    }
    return false;
}
```

basically what this code do is checking each last digit if it's equals to 7 if not he divides the num by 10 and remove the last digit and after checking again, it will do so until no digit left (num=0) or he will find 7.

Comment: Thank you for your help, kind of a newb when it comes to this kind of thing. For now I'm going with Jordi Castilla answer! :-)